# Migration to RichFaces 4: HtmlAjaxCommandLink -> UICommandButton

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I convert legacy project to more modern libraries version.
The older version used the following **ajax4jsf** code:

```
HtmlAjaxCommandLink link = new HtmlAjaxCommandLink()
link.addAjaxListener(new AjaxListener() {
    @Override
    public void processAjax(AjaxEvent event) { }
});
```

According to the documentation, *HtmlAjaxCommandLink* was replaced by *UICommandLink* in Richfaces 4.

Though, I cannot seem to fine a replacement for *addAjaxListener* for the control.

What can it be replaced with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JSF2, ajax has been standardized by the JSF API. All components supporting client behavior should implement [`ClientBehaviorHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) which in turn offers the [`addClientBehavior()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html#addClientBehavior%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehavior%29) method to add client behavior. A concrete client behavior implementation for ajax is the [`AjaxBehavior`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/AjaxBehavior.html) which in turn offers the [`addAjaxBehaviorListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/AjaxBehavior.html#addAjaxBehaviorListener%28javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorListener%29) method which is exactly what you're looking for.

All with all, in your particular case, it can be replaced as follows:

```
UICommandLink link = new UICommandLink(); // Note: you can also just use standard JSF HtmlCommandLink.
link.setId("linkId"); // Fixed ID is mandatory for successful processing.
link.setValue("click here"); // Not sure if you need it. Just to be complete.
AjaxBehavior ajaxAction = new AjaxBehavior();
ajaxAction.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListener() {
    @Override
    public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Ajax behavior listener invoked."); // Do your actual job jere.
    }
});
link.addClientBehavior("action", ajaxAction); // Note: don't use "click" event!
```

Comment: I am having a hard time finding imports for AjaxBehavior,  AjaxBehaviorEvent, AbortProcessingException. Any chance, you can copy-paste those imports from the code? Thanks!

Comment: Click the links. They all point to the javadoc. Or just press Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse and handpick if necessary the ones from `javax.faces` package.